# Obtener el Valor de un Arreglo a través del Indice PostgreSQL

Tags: array, postgresql, loops

Buenas tardes amigos, tengo mucho tiempo con mi cuenta de StackOverflow, y no sabia que había uno en español "/ jejeje bueno al punto.

Tengo una función que estoy armando para modificar el costo de un articulo, para ello paso como parámetro: cod_cart,cant,costo (como lo compre), ambos 3 como array.

Dentro de la función pretendo buscar el articulo en la tabla de artículos y traerme sus costos, si estos no cumplen ciertas condiciones los re-formulo.

Mi problema aparece cuando estoy en el 1er arreglo (Hago un select de la tabla articulos utilizando como condicional los valor del 1er arreglo), para compararlo, si obtengo 0 en su costo actual le quiero asignar el costo actual que se utilizó al comprar, en cuestión si estoy en el indice 3 del 1er arreglo, quiero que me tome como costo el valor del indice 3 del 2do arreglo . . .

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION fun(
IN _cart_comercial integer[],
IN _cant integer[],
IN _costu numeric[]
)
RETURNS TABLE(art_comercial character varying(60), costo_prom numeric(11,2), costo_ant numeric(11,2),costo_act numeric(11,2),costo_ingresado numeric(11,2)) AS
$func$
DECLARE
BEGIN
    FOR art_comercial, costo_prom, costo_ant, costo_act, costo_ingresado IN
    SELECT a.art_comercial, a.costo_prom,a.costo_ant,a.costo_actual--,t.*
    FROM   art_comercial a--,(SELECT UNNEST(_costu)) t
    WHERE  a.cart_comercial IN  (SELECT UNNEST(_cart_comercial))
    ORDER  BY a.art_comercial

    LOOP
        IF ((costo_prom<=0) OR (costo_prom IS NULL)) THEN
            --AQUI TECNICAMENTE LE ASIGNARIA A COSTO_PROM, EL VALOR QUE POSEE EL ARREGLO _COSTU SEGÚN EL INDICE.
            costo_prom:=0;
            costo_ant:=0;
            costo_act:=0;
        ELSE
            costo_act:=1;
        END IF;
        RETURN NEXT;
    END LOOP;
END
$func$ LANGUAGE plpgsql STABLE
```

La función la invoco

```
select * from fun('{1,2}','{5,7}','{50,70}');
```

Dicha función la estoy haciendo de muestra, una vez obtenga lo que busco lo pretendo armar de forma completa.

Espero puedan ayudarme :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Logre resolverlo creando una variable y utilizandola como contador:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION fun(
IN _cart_comercial integer[],
IN _cant integer[],
IN _und integer[],
IN _costu numeric[]
)
RETURNS TABLE(art_comercial character varying(60), costo_prom numeric(11,2), costo_ant numeric(11,2),costo_act numeric(11,2)) AS
$func$
DECLARE
    c integer=1; --Utilice C como contador
    mul integer;
    compra numeric(11,2);
    exist numeric(11,2);
BEGIN
    FOR art_comercial, costo_prom, costo_ant, costo_act IN
    SELECT a.art_comercial, a.costo_prom,a.costo_ant,a.costo_actual
    FROM   art_comercial a
    WHERE  a.cart_comercial IN  (SELECT UNNEST(_cart_comercial))
    ORDER  BY a.art_comercial

    LOOP
        mul:= (SELECT multiplicador from art_und WHERE cunidad=_und[c]);
        compra:=((_cant[c]*_costu[c])/(_cant[c]*mul));
        exist:=(SELECT cantidad from art_comercial WHERE cart_comercial=_cart_comercial[c]);
        IF ((costo_prom<=0) OR (costo_prom IS NULL)) THEN
            costo_prom:=compra;
            costo_ant:=compra;
            costo_act:=compra;
        ELSE
            costo_ant:=costo_act;
            costo_act:=compra;
            costo_prom:=(((exist*costo_ant)+(compra))/(exist+mul));
        END IF;
        RETURN NEXT;
        c=c+1; --Por cada Ciclo lo aumento y lo utilizo como INDICE
    END LOOP;
END
$func$ LANGUAGE plpgsql STABLE
```

Tecnicamente asi logro lo que deseo hacer